# Remove Account Team Member

Tags: trigger, account-teams

I have successfully created a trigger that will add a Team Member when a custom field on the Account object is populated, but I am now trying to add code that will remove that same Team Member when the custom field is blank.  This is what I have, but the Team Member is not being deleted.  Thanks

Trigger:

```
trigger UpdateBankRepTeam on Account (After update, After insert){
    UpdateBRHelper.updateTeamMember(trigger.new);
}
```

Class:

```
   public class UpdateBRHelper{
        public static void updateTeamMember(List<Account> accounts){

            List<AccountShare> ashareLIST = new List<AccountShare>();
            List<AccountTeamMember> ATM = new List<AccountTeamMember>();
            Set<String> rmMember = new Set<String>();
            Map<ID, ID> acctToBRepMap = new Map<ID, ID>();

            for(Account a:accounts){

                AccountShare caSharingRule = new AccountShare();
                   caSharingRule.AccountId = a.Id;
                   caSharingRule.OpportunityAccessLevel = 'Edit';
                   caSharingRule.CaseAccessLevel = 'Edit';
                   caSharingRule.AccountAccessLevel = 'Edit';
                   caSharingRule.UserOrGroupId = a.Banking_Rep__c;
                   ashareLIST.add(caSharingRule);

               if(a.Banking_Rep__c != null){
                  AccountTeamMember Teammemberad=new AccountTeamMember();
                  Teammemberad.AccountId=a.id;
                  Teammemberad.UserId=a.Banking_Rep__c;
                  Teammemberad.TeamMemberRole = 'Banking Rep';
                  ATM.add(Teammemberad);
            }
            if(!ATM.isEmpty()){
               insert ATM;           
               insert ashareLIST;
               }  
            if(rmMember.size() > 0)
            {
            List<AccountTeamMember> removeTeam = new List<AccountTeamMember>();
                for(AccountTeamMember Ratm : [SELECT Id, UserId, AccountId FROM AccountTeamMember WHERE TeamMemberRole='Banking Rep' AND AccountId IN :rmMember])
                {
                    if(Ratm.UserId == acctToBRepMap.get(Ratm.AccountId))
                        removeTeam.add(Ratm);
                }

                delete removeTeam;
            }     
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: There is no where in your code that you are checking for the Banking_Rep__c to be null.

I am confused on your logic as in  you code you are:

1. If the Banking rep is NOT null, remove them if they are on the account team.

Thus if the field is null and was previously set t a value that Team Member should have been previously removed. Thus if it is null there is nothing to remove....

Answer (score 1):

> I dont see how your SET and MAP are filled in the above code

```
 Set<String> rmMember = new Set<String>();
 Map<ID, ID> acctToBRepMap = new Map<ID, ID>();
```

The above variables are not populated .